# Can't save Magento2 product in integration test

Tags: magento2

I am working on an integration test for a project called the [Magento2 Configurator](https://github.com/ctidigital/magento2-configurator).

I'm using the latest version of Magento CE.

It need to programmatically set up some fixture products, however Magento doesn't seem to save the product to the database.

I have a [branch](https://github.com/alexbiddle/MX_magento2_configurator/commit/855101b5a3637f7cbcffb4252007efce879c695d) and an excerpt of the code is below:

```
    // given a yaml file 
    $yamlParser = new Parser();
    $testCatalogPriceRules = $yamlParser->parse(file_get_contents($this->testCatalogPriceRulesYamlPath), true);

    // and a sample product
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
    $productModel = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()
        ->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

    $productModel->setName("Cool 123");
    $productModel->setAttributeSetId(1);
    $productModel->setShortDescription("Cool 123");
    $productModel->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $productModel->setVisibility(4);
    $productModel->setDescription("Cool 123");
    $productModel->setSku("SKU");
    $productModel->save();

    // and a customer group

    // when we run the AdminRoles component
    $this->catalogPriceRulesComponent->processData($testCatalogPriceRules);

    // then it should enter new catalog price rules into the database
```

The problem is, is that what I run the test with

```
/var/www/magento2/dev/tests/integration$ ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite "magento2-configurator" --filter="testShouldCreateNewCatalogPriceRulesFromYamlFile"
```

And check the database using mysqldump, nothing seems to be entered.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/var/www/magento2/var/log$ mysqldump -u root -p magento_integration_tests | grep -i  "Cool" -C5
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
-- Dumping data for table `url_rewrite`
--

LOCK TABLES `url_rewrite` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `url_rewrite` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `url_rewrite` VALUES (1,'cms-page',1,'no-route','cms/page/view/page_id/1',0,1,NULL,1,NULL),(2,'cms-page',2,'home','cms/page/view/page_id/2',0,1,NULL,1,NULL),(3,'cms-page',3,'enable-cookies','cms/page/view/page_id/3',0,1,NULL,1,NULL),(4,'cms-page',4,'privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode','cms/page/view/page_id/4',0,1,NULL,1,NULL),(5,'product',1,'cool-123.html','catalog/product/view/id/1',0,1,NULL,1,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `url_rewrite` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `variable`
```

Comment: dump what this returns $this->catalogPriceRulesComponent->processData($testCatalogPriceRules);  $productModel->save();

Comment: $productModel->save()->getId() returns 1. I'll have to install xdebug as there are some circular references that prevent print_r and friends from working.